# How do I release the Google map memory being used in Android development?

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks

The site listed below uses Google Maps. However, I keep getting a notification from `leakcanary` that memory is not being released. How can I free memory?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start?hl=ko

For reference, I am using Googlemap in Fragment.
Here's what I've tried:

```
private var map: GoogleMap? = null
private var mapFragment: SupportMapFragment? = null

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googlemap
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)    
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    map?.clear()
    mapFragment?.onDestroy()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `super.onDestroyView()`.

---

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        map?.clear()
        mapFragment?.onDestroy()
        map = null
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to use ```super.onDestroyView()```. What I mean is that in the actual code ```super.onDestroyView()``` is written. I didn't use ```super.onDestroyView()``` in the post I was asking about... I'll edit it.

Comment: I also tried running the ```map = null``` you mentioned, but there is still a memory leak problem.